# Checking if input has letters in it

Tags: python, set, operand

My error appears on this line:

```
if exclude3 not in Sent:
```

And it is:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not set
```

My code is:

```
import string

Word = input("Please give a word from the sentence")

exclude3 = set(string.ascii_letters)

if exclude3 not in Sent:
    print("")
elif exclude3 not in Word:
    print("")
else:
```

What is a left operand? What am I doing wrong and is there a simpler way to accomplish what I want? Should I be using something other than `in` and what should that be?

Comment: what do you hope to achieve with this code? your error is self explanatory but what you are trying to do is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exclude3` is not a `string` it is a `set`.
You try to use the `in` operator to check if a `set` is contained in another `set` which is wrong.

Maybe you meant to write: `if Sent not in exclude3` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the set and the string overlap. Either

```
if not exclude3.intersection(Sent):
```

or

```
if not any(x in Sent for x in exclude3):
```

will have the desired result.

The `in` operator works by testing if the left-hand argument is an element of the right-hand argument. The exception is `str1 in str2`, which tests if the left-hand `str` is a *substring* of the other.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick and good responses, it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `in` operand the left side and right side objects must be same type. And in this case `exclude3` is a `set` object and you can not check its membership in a string.

Example:

```
>>> [] in ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

If you want to check the existence of all the items of a set in a string you can use `set.intersection()` as following :

```
if exclude3.interection(Sent) == exclude3:
      # do stuff
```

And for any intersection just check the validation of `exclude3.interection(Sent)`:

```
if exclude3.interection(Sent):
     # do stuff
```